# How to send any file (image, exe) through UDP in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, udp, winsock2

I'm trying to implement transmission of files through UDP protocol in C++.
What I've got is the server which can send a file requested by a client, but it only works for .txt files. When I try to do the same with image or executable, the transmission corrupts and the file is about 0 KB.

Server:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define cipherKey 'S'

int const bufferSize = 512;
char buffer[bufferSize];

void clearBuf(char* b)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
        b[i] = '\0';
}

char* notFound = "File not found.";

char Cipher(char ch)
{
    return ch ^ cipherKey;
}

int sendFile(FILE* file, char* buffer, int s)
{
    int i, len;
    if (file == NULL)
    {
        strcpy(buffer, notFound);
        len = strlen(notFound);
        buffer[len] = EOF;
        return 1;
    }

    char ch, ch2;
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        ch = fgetc(file);
        ch2 = Cipher(ch);
        buffer[i] = ch2;
        if (ch == EOF)
            return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wynik_winsock = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    if(wynik_winsock != 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET socketServer;
    socketServer = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if(socketServer == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    char* ipAdd = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 1234;

    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipAdd);

    if(bind(socketServer, (SOCKADDR *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(socketServer);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "Waiting." << std::endl;

    SOCKADDR_IN client;
    int len_client = sizeof(client);

    FILE* file;
    if(recvfrom(socketServer, buffer, bufferSize, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&client, &len_client) == SOCKET_ERROR) //Odbiór danych od clienta wraz z kontrolą błędów.
    {
        closesocket(socketServer);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        file = fopen(buffer, "rb");
        std::cout << "Filename: " << buffer << std::endl;
        if(file == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Couldnt open a file." << std::endl;
        }
        else
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if(sendFile(file, buffer, bufferSize))
                {
                    sendto(socketServer, buffer, bufferSize, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&client, len_client);
                    break;
                }

                sendto(socketServer, buffer, bufferSize, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&client, len_client);
                clearBuf(buffer);
            }
            fclose(file);
        }
    }
    closesocket(socketServer);
    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Client:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

#define cipherKey 'S'

int const bufferSize = 512;
char buffer[bufferSize];

void clearBuf(char* b)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < bufferSize; i++)
        b[i] = '\0';
}

char Cipher(char ch)
{
    return ch ^ cipherKey;
}

int recvFile(char* buffer, int s, FILE* file)
{
    int i;
    char ch;
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        ch = buffer[i];
        ch = Cipher(ch);
        if (ch == EOF)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            fprintf(file, "%c", ch);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int wynik_winsock = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    if(wynik_winsock != 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET socketClient;
    socketClient = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if(socketClient == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    char* ipAdd = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 1234;

    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ipAdd);

    int serverSizeOf = sizeof(server);

    std::cout << "Name of file to send: ";
    std::cin >> buffer;

    if(sendto(socketClient, buffer, bufferSize, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&server, serverSizeOf) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(socketClient);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(buffer, "ab");

    while (true)
    {
        clearBuf(buffer);
        if(recvfrom(socketClient, buffer, bufferSize, 0, (SOCKADDR *)&server, &serverSizeOf) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            closesocket(socketClient);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(1);
        }

        if (recvFile(buffer, bufferSize, file))
        {
            break;
        }
        fclose(file);
    }


    closesocket(socketClient);
    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```

To do what I said above, I used the tutorial: [C program for file Transfer using UDP (Linux)](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-for-file-transfer-using-udp/).
How can I adapt the code to send other files than .txt only? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The [`fgetc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) function returns an **`int`**. This is actually very important for the comparison against `EOF`.

Comment: Also, what happens if you  transfer a file which is *not* a multiple of `bufferSize`?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude For 2B and 258B text files it works just fine.

Comment: Also, what happens if the UDP packages comes to the client out of order? What happens if a packet goes missing? Use TCP for transferring files to a single destination.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I have to use UDP because of guidelines from our lecturer.

Comment: There is little point in sending a file over an unreliable protocol, where packets may arrive out of order or disappear completely. (geeksforgeeks.com is not a good site.)

Comment: @molbdnilo Yeah, but I still have to use UDP as I said above.

Comment: @norbi1952 Too bad. It's not suitable for this. You need to implement your own packet number schema to make sure you get the packages in the correct order and that no package is missing.

Comment: In the client you do `file = fopen(buffer, "ab");`, but what happens if the file already exists?

Comment: `char* notFound = "File not found.";` is invalid, missing const.

Comment: Lastly, have you tried to debug the programs? Really step through the code inside a debugger to see what happens?

Comment: @norbi1952 You send an image file, and the bytes are out of order or missing, the image file is invalid.  This is not a good usage of UDP.  Why no one brought this point up with the lecturer and have him/her explain?

Comment: @norbi1952 That's a very silly requirement, *unless* this is actually an exercise in discovering the unreliability and implementing your own reliable protocol on top of UDP. In which case it would be a very reasonable requirement.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude As far as i know, because of the flag "a", additional content will be just appended to the file. With text files it works just fine, but with executables it will be a problem. Right.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Probably, as molbdnilo said, it is an exercise which would show us how unreliable UDP is. Anyway, the file is still about 0KB size instead of, for example, 25KB. Shouldn't it be still as big as the original one, just in different order (corrupted)?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Now, when I changed `fgetc` type to int as you said, the remaining bytes are filled with _S_ letter, as I think, from `char Cipher(char ch)` function.

Comment: @norbi1952 What remaining bits? It's not very clear what you mean. Really you need to use a debugger (I'm assuming you haven't so far).

Comment: @john Sorry, I meant bytes from the `bufferSize`. I'm not really good with debugger, but I tried sth and I can see that those bytes are not filled by `Cipher`. The content of buffer when it comes to sending is just fine.

Comment: @norbi1952 OK, so sending is fine, that's progress. Looking at your recieving code the problem seems to me to be that you are not using the return value of `recvfrom` which tells you how many bytes you recieved. Also the logic in `recvFile` is incorrect. You will never get an EOF in a character buffer, EOF isn't a character, it's a special return value you get when reading from a file. So basically the logic of the receiving code is wrong. There must be plenty of examples of the internet of how to read from a socket.

Comment: The best way to transfer a file (of any type) via UDP is to use an established UDP-based file transfer protocol, such as [TFTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_File_Transfer_Protocol).  Don't try to re-invent your own protocol.

Comment: @john I've figured it out and now received text files are equal to original ones, but I still don't know how to send images or executables using the program.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yeah, maybe but as I said before, according to my lecturer, I have to write a program which will send executable file from server to client using UDP. It doesn't sound to me like I could use TFTP.

Comment: @norbi1952 yes, you can use TFTP. It is a UDP-based protocol, and it is not very difficult to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to change nearly everything in the original solution I tried to implement. The most important changes are reading file using `fread` and writing it using `fwrite`.
The file is send in parts of 512 bytes (or less) and those parts are counted in the variable.
If the file requested by a client doesn't exist on the server, special information is sent and the file created to save data is deleted.
Now the program works as expected even for executables and SHA256 of both files, original and received, are the same.
**Server**:

```
//SERVER

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int winsock_result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    if(winsock_result != 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET server_socket;
    server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if(server_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    char* ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 6666;

    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);

    if(bind(server_socket,(SOCKADDR *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(server_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    std::cout << "Waiting for data." << std::endl;

    SOCKADDR_IN client;
    int client_sizeof = sizeof(client);

    int const buffer_size = 512;
    char buffer[buffer_size];

    if(recvfrom(server_socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0,(SOCKADDR *)&client, &client_sizeof) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(server_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }
    else
    {
        FILE* file;
        file = fopen(buffer, "rb");
        std::cout << "Filename: " << buffer << std::endl;

        if(file == NULL)
        {
            std::cout << "Couldn't open the file." << std::endl;

            strcpy(buffer, "NOFILE");
            if(sendto(server_socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0,(SOCKADDR *)&client, client_sizeof) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                fclose(file);
                closesocket(server_socket);
                WSACleanup();
                exit(1);
            }
        }

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        int file_size = ftell(file);

        size_t reading_size;
        int part = 0;

        const clock_t begin_time = clock();

        while((part * buffer_size) < file_size)
        {
            fseek(file, (part * buffer_size), SEEK_SET);
            reading_size = fread(buffer, 1, buffer_size, file);

            if(sendto(server_socket, buffer, reading_size, 0,(SOCKADDR *)&client, client_sizeof) == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                fclose(file);
                closesocket(server_socket);
                WSACleanup();
                exit(1);
            }
            part++;
        }
        std::cout << "Sent " << part << " parts of " << buffer_size << " bytes." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Time of sending file: " << float( clock () - begin_time ) /  CLOCKS_PER_SEC << " seconds." << std::endl;

        strcpy(buffer, "QUIT");
        if(sendto(server_socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0,(SOCKADDR *)&client, client_sizeof) == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            fclose(file);
            closesocket(server_socket);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(1);
        }
        fclose(file);
    }
    closesocket(server_socket);
    WSACleanup();

    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

**Client**:

```
//CLIENT

#include <winsock2.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")

int main()
{
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int winsock_result = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);

    if(winsock_result != 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    SOCKET client_socket;
    client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    if(client_socket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    char* ip_address = "127.0.0.1";
    int port = 6666;

    SOCKADDR_IN server;
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_port = htons(port);
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(ip_address);

    int server_sizeof = sizeof(server);

    int const buffer_size = 512;
    char buffer[buffer_size];

    std::cout << "Name of the requested file: ";
    std::cin >> buffer;

    char filename[buffer_size];
    strcpy(filename, buffer);

    if(sendto(client_socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0,(SOCKADDR *)&server, server_sizeof) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        closesocket(client_socket);
        WSACleanup();
        exit(1);
    }

    FILE* file;
    file = fopen(filename, "wb");

    int received_size = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        received_size = recvfrom(client_socket, buffer, buffer_size, 0,(SOCKADDR *)&server, &server_sizeof);
        if(received_size == SOCKET_ERROR)
        {
            fclose(file);
            closesocket(client_socket);
            WSACleanup();
            exit(1);
        }
        if(strcmp(buffer, "NOFILE") == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "The file does not exist on the server." << std::endl;

            fclose(file);
            remove(filename);

            break;
        }
        else if(strcmp(buffer, "QUIT") == 0)
        {
            std::cout << "Transmission ended by the server." << std::endl;
            break;
        }
        fwrite(buffer, sizeof(char), received_size, file);
    }
    fclose(file);

    closesocket(client_socket);
    WSACleanup();
    system("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

As said in the comments above you need a data type where `EOF` has a different value from all other character values, `char` is inadequate in this respect, especially when you are dealing with binary data.

The following change should improve things

```
int sendFile(FILE* file, char* buffer, int s)
{
    ...
    for (i = 0; i < s; i++)
    {
        int ch = fgetc(file);
        if (ch == EOF)
            return 1;
        buffer[i] = Cipher(ch);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: `recvFile` has also issue.